Not a supported wheel on this platform. (only online installation supported)
My host machine is windows but got a python project running on linux. So I started utilizing Docker to containerize a Ubuntu os equipped with tensorflow, which I already downloaded its .whl file and COPY to my image. However when using pip3 install ...whl it showed the error ERROR: tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. My Dockerfile is as follows:
FROM ubuntu:latest

# Update and install necessary packages

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.7
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip

# Set the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the wheel file from your local directory to the container
COPY tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl /app/
COPY tensorflow_compression-1.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl /app/

# Install required dependancies
RUN pip3 install range-coder
RUN pip3 install tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl # Error at this line!
RUN pip3 install tensorflow_compression-1.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

I've tried using pip3 install tensorflow==1.14.0 directly from online repository BUT this edition couldn't be found with python3.7
The project originally asked to use python 3.6. In that case tensorflow1.14.0 can be found in online repository but another dependancy requires at least 3.7 for python :(
RUN pip3 install tensorflow==1.14.0
Collecting tensorflow==1.14.0
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/f0/96fb2e0412ae9692dbf400e5b04432885f677ad6241c088ccc5fe7724d69/tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (109.2MB)
.
.（other packages being downloaded）
.
protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.9

From the runtime error report I can tell the tensorflow it downloaded online is exactly tensorflow-1.14.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl, which in my work I already have this wheel prepared. So why Ubuntu refuses to recognize this wheel when installing locally.

Hi @juzhong , you are facing an error while installing the tensorflow-1.14.0 which is not compatible with the python version, try to install the correct version of python 3.6 instead of 3.7 in your docker image which is compatible tensorflow or you can upgrade to tensorflow 2.x which support python 3.7 . Try this if you are still facing an issue let me know,Thanks.
